# Custom Error Handler and Try - Catch - how to handle errors and warnings cleanly

Tags: php, error-handling, try-catch

I am trying to better understand exception handling. I have a custom error handler. When the following function is run without a mail server present, it correctly trips the error handler and returns "Tough Luck". In the error handler, I have to `throw new ErrorException()` in order for the `try/catch` to be activated. Without this statement, after the error, the program will continue with the next line of code (in this case returning "Feedback left").

To be able to continue with the next line of code is useful since the user doesn't get blaring error messages and warnings. However, I want to be able to use Try/Catch in selected cases.

What is a better way to handle errors where the user does not see them but I can use try/catch? Is there a way to throw new ErrorException (with $e->getSeverity()?) where if a try/catch is present it is processed, but if not, the exception is ignored?

```
set_error_handler('exceptions_error_handler');
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT);

echo feedback();

function feedback(){
    try{
        mail("m@localhost","subject","body","From: me");
        return "Feedback left.";
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        error_log("Error sending feedback email." . "Some Custom Info For Error Log");
        return "Tough Luck";
    }
}


function exceptions_error_handler( $errno, $errmsg, $errfile, $errline, $context = null ){
    // custom log file handling
    log_exception( new ErrorException( $errmsg, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline) );

    // required in order for the try/catch to be activated
    throw new ErrorException($errmsg, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, Exceptions (or any subclass thereof) will stop program execution if they are not caught. What you are probably wanting to do is to `set_exception_handler()` to be able handle any uncaught exceptions that may occur in your code.

More generally, you need to decide on your strategy for dealing with Exceptions and errors.  For most people, Exceptions are thrown when the application gets into an unexpected state (such as not having a mail server, losing database connectivity, etc.). Errors may contribute to how you get into such a state or be triggered when you get in such a state, but won't necessarily be something that would cause you to potentially change the way the application behaves (like to terminate request early).

As an example, for your case, I might consider something like this:

```
try {
   echo feedback();
} catch(Exception $e) {
   echo 'Feedback failed with exception: ' . $e->message;
}

function feedback() {
   $success = mail(...);
   if (false === $success) {
        $error_info = error_get_last();
        throw new Exception('Mail failed with error: ' . $error_info['message']);
   } else {
       return 'Feedback Left';
   }
}
```

Usually you might wrap try-catch blocks around individual function of class method calls rather than try to create a try-catch block within the function itself.  So in essence you are `try`ing to call the feedback function and you are catching any Exception that might be raised while doing so.

In well-written code you might see `throw` near the beginning of most function/method code blocks to validate input, as having invalid input would indicate the application being in an unexpected state. So something like:

```
public function set_foo($bar = NULL) {
    if(is_null($bar)) {
        throw new Exception('A value must be passed for $bar');
    }

    // perform method logic
}
```

It is generally good practice to "exit early" from methods/functions where you are throwing an Expcetion.  In other words, where possible, check all your dependencies and throw appropriate Exception right at the beginning of a code block before you execute logic that may do things like change application state.  It also greatly helps with code readability to have Exception logic grouped up front in such a manner.

Comment: Wow. I'm embarrassed to say I've never realized there was a set_`exception_handler()` in addition to `set_error_handler`. I can't easily tell from the docs what differences it will make. I appreciate the clarification on the use of try/catch. It seems I have had the functionality backwards in my conception of how it should be used. But... in your example, won't mail() throw an exception before it ever gets to test for `if (false === $success)`? How would my exception handler deal with it - wouldn't it usually throw an exception as well?

Comment: If my exception_error_handler does NOT throw a new exception, I see that this would allow me then to throw my own exceptions on a case by case basis within the function being tested if I write the code as you have shown. Correct?

Comment: @mseifert `mail()` should not thrown an exception on its own.  Even if it does, it would be caught by the try-catch block around your call to `feedback()`.  I honestly don't know why you would use an `exceptions_error_handler()` as you are doing, as to me it would not be good coding practice to in essence change all errors into Exceptions.  You should definitely feel free to throw Exceptions anywhere in your code where you feel you are getting into a condition that your expected use cases will not normally produce.

Comment: @mseifert That is a whole additional level of strategy around use of custom Exception types (for example to be able to pass along to a calling client that an Exception is transient in nature and the request should be retired, perform custom logging behavior, etc.).  But you should probably get familiar with basic Exception handling before really delving into these.

Comment: In response to why change all errors into exceptions: I acutally don't `throw new ErrorException()` with the custom errorhandler although I've seen the code posted this way many times. I use the exception-handler to log all errors and warnings and so debug my code and track run-time problems. I've only just now realized the relationship between `throw new ErrorException()` and try/catch. Your answer should get me through.